# retrieveing info from python dict with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, json

I have such stuff in my django view:

```
message = 'sometext'
rating = 7
data = {'message':message, 'rating':rating}
from django.utils import simplejson
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

and this in my site.js:

```
$.ajax({
 'type': "POST",
 'url': url,
 'data': {'rating':rating},
 'success': function(msg){
  alert(msg['rating']);
  $.modal('<p>'+msg+'</p>');
  $(".simplemodal-container").css("height", "auto");
 },
 'error' : function(){
  $.modal('<p>Hinnangu salvestamine ebaõnnestus</p>');
  $(".simplemodal-container").css("height", "auto");
 }
});
```

the simplemodel window returns me information like this:

```
{"rating": "7", "message": "sometext"}
```

alert on previous line just returns 'undefined'

Why? Whats missing?
i read about javascript dictionaries here: 
http://rick.measham.id.au/javascript/hash.htm
and according to that, the alert should display '7' not 'undefined' or not?

Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it contains that. That's the JSON that has been returned to you. Use [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) to decode it to JavaScript objects.

Comment: Thanks. the json2.js and
    var myObject = JSON.parse(msg);
    alert(myObject['message']);
was exactly what i needed